# Probability that at least 1 person from a group of N people will be in the top M places out of K total people?

Tags: probability

Imagine you have a group of N people that each make a submission. There are K submissions total. What is the probability that at least 1 person from the group of N people will be in one of the top M places assuming each place has an equal probability.

For example, a group of 10 people each make a submission. There are 100 submissions total. What the is the probability that at least 1 of the 10 people will be in the top 3 places assuming that each person has an equal probability to be in each place and only 1 person can be in each place.

Comment: Is this homework? Here's an equivalent question: There are 100 balls in an urn. 10 are red, the rest are black. We mix well and draw 3 at random. What is the probability that at least one of the three balls drawn are red?  ... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution  (there are many questions about it on site)  ... You don't have to use the hypergeometric, though, since you can do it directly using simple reasoning -- it's just P(at least one red) = 1-P(no red) = 1-P(draw a black, then another black, then another black).